# AngularJS on old WebForms

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, webforms, asp.net-apicontroller

I need help working with Angular 1.5 on an existing old website (WebForms/Umbraco 4).

**GET works**

C#

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public string Test(int id)
    {
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

JS

```
$http.get("/api/My/Test?id=1");
```

**but POST doesn't work**

C#

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public string Test(int id)
    {
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

JS

```
$http.post("/api/My/Test", {id: 1});
```

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:8431/api/My/Test'.

How to make it work with POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing that solves the issue

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public string Test()
{
    string jsonStr = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    dynamic data = JObject.Parse(jsonStr);
    var id = data.id.Value;
    return "ok";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the id as part of the request body, so you need to define it as such.

Try

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public string Test([FromBody] int id)
    {
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

Notice the [[FromBody]](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) attribute in the method declaration for Test()

Comment: Thank you Joniff! I still can't get it to work  
> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String Test(Int32)' in 'MyController'.